# PHP "auto_prepend_file" Causes HTTP 200 Responses For Every File Including Non-Existent Files

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-codes, prepend, php-ini

## My Setup

I have a website hosted on SiteGround with a **php.ini** file located in my web root containing only the following:

```
auto_prepend_file = "${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/config.php"
```

The file config.php contains some global/static define() variables to be used throughout my entire solution that I want to reference/load on every PHP page accessed by visitors. I not only want this file to work on the current directory, but also recursively below it. To achieve this recursive behavior, SiteGround edited my **.htaccess** file at the web root to have the following single line:

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/user/public_html/example.com/php.ini
```

These two files working together (**php.ini** and **.htaccess**) achieve my desired behavior for PHP files and pages I load through a browser. For example, when I go to /index.php (root index) or /some/folder/lower/index.php (sub-folder index) the config.php file is prepended appropriately and I can access the values I set up in that file using define().

## My Problem

The problem I'm facing is that the prepended file is apparently being "attached" to every file in my directories—and not just PHP files like I expected. I first noticed this when my page's debug output was sending 3 messages to my console when the page was only loaded once. Upon further investigating it turned out that a non-existent Favicon and CSS file were the source of the erroneous messages.

Those missing files *should have* responded with a 404 HTTP status, but instead they returned as 200 (presumably since the config.php was prepended to it) and what loaded in its place was curiously my web root's index.php file content (regardless of folder depth). Those non-existent .ico and .css files appear as if they're being prepended with the config.php when they shouldn't be and then—for whatever reason—including my web root's index.php content. Instead, the HTTP status codes should be getting back to the client as traditional 404 errors and *not* have the config.php applied to them. I am so confused as to what the problem is here.

## My Questions

I want to know the following:

1. Is there a way for me to specify in my **php.ini** file that the `auto_prepend_file` should only apply/execute/interpret for *.php files?
2. Is this a server setting that's hidden from my view that would impact this at all? I don't have any ErrorDocument handlers configured yet.
3. Can anyone explain or shed light on why a non-PHP file would have config.php prepended to it?
4. Can anyone explain why for non-existent files (that should be HTTP 404 responses) it's loading my web root's index.php content?

Comment: Do you have any URL rewriting in place for routing purposes? Sounds like all your 404s might get rewritten to the index.php internally.

Comment: OMG a directory above the web root in question was hosting a Wordpress site and _that_ .htaccess had rewrite rules which were being applied. I can't believe I didn't check that until I read your comment which put me on the right path. Thanks @CBroe!

Comment: For anyone else here for a similar reason you should check .htaccess files (or other config files) above your directory to see if they're impacting things. Also, the auto_prepend_file _wasn't_ being applied to all files. Rather, since my errant .htaccess file in the directory above was causing my web root's index.php to be loaded for all files it was accordingly loading the config.php file. So it _was_ loading that only for PHP files correctly which I interpreted incorrectly.